# Improving a priority queue sketch in Racket/Scheme

Tags: algorithm, scheme, racket

I just put together the skeletons for a priority queue using a binary heap in racket/scheme. Using racket/scheme is all about the educational experience and I was wondering if anyone  wants to critique and improve the code. Bug reports are welcome

```
;; priority queues operations on integer values

(define (heap)
  (let ((the-heap (make-vector 10)) (next-free 1))

(define (swim val) 
  (begin 
    (vector-set! the-heap next-free val)
    (set! next-free (+ next-free 1))
    (let loop ((i (- next-free 1)))
      (if (and (< (vector-ref the-heap (quotient i 2)) (vector-ref the-heap i)) (> (quotient i 2) 0))
          (begin 
            (exch the-heap i (floor (/ i 2)))
            (loop (floor (/ i 2))))
        the-heap))))

(define (sink index) 
  ;; a call to this method is used to re-establish order within the
  ;; heap by 'sinking' the value rooted at index to its right position
  ;; within the whole heap
  (let loop ((node index) (kid (* 2 index)))
    (if (<= kid next-free)
        (let ((larger-kid (if (> (vector-ref the-heap kid) (vector-ref the-heap (+ kid 1)))
                                 kid
                                 (+ kid 1))))
          (if (> (vector-ref the-heap larger-kid) (vector-ref the-heap node))
              (begin
                (exch the-heap node larger-kid)
                (loop larger-kid (* 2 larger-kid)))
              the-heap))
          (newline))))

(define (delete-max)
  ;; delete and return the maximum value in the heap.
  ;; add the last item on the heap to the root position 
  ;; sink to re-establish order within the heap of the heap and call
  ;; 
  (begin 
    (let ((val (vector-ref the-heap 1)))
      (vector-set! the-heap 1 (vector-ref the-heap (- next-free 1)))
      (set! next-free (- next-free 1))
      (vector-set! the-heap next-free 0)
      (sink 1)
      val)))


(define (put value) 
  (swim value))

(define (size) 
  (vector-length the-heap))

(define (empty?) 
  (= next-free 1))

(define (exch vec lo j)
  (let ((lo-val (vector-ref vec lo)) (j-val (vector-ref vec j)))
    (begin
      (vector-set! vec lo j-val)
      (vector-set! vec j lo-val))))

(define (dispatch message . arg)
  (cond 
    ((eq? message 'delete-max) (delete-max))
    ((eq? message 'put) (put (car arg)))
    ((eq? message 'size) size)
    ((eq? message 'heap) the-heap)
    ((eq? message 'empty?) empty?)))
dispatch))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some general points before I start on more specific points:

- I don't see any unit tests. Racket programmers often write many unit tests for each function. You can use the [`module+`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html) construct and [`rackunit`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/) to easily write internal unit tests.
- Indentation is important for clarity. I couldn't tell that everything was internal to `heap` at first because of the lack of indentation. Also, you can replace some of the `let`s with internal `define`s and make some of the internal functions into top-level functions to reduce right-ward drift.

More specific points:

- It looks like you're using a dispatch function with internal state to keep track of the priority queue state. The more natural thing to do in Racket would be to create a new datatype using `struct`. This way, your implementation details don't leak through.
- You use a `dispatch` function as the entry point to your simulated object. Simulating OO style in this fashion is not a very natural thing to do in Racket. Racket programmers tend to either use (1) the built-in classes & objects or (2) have a functional API with a function for each operation.
- You use `begin` to sequence multiple effecting operations inside functions. These are actually unnecessary since Racket functions can have as many expressions in the body as you like.

Hope that helps. Cheers.